# Why does mounting proc in my chroot fail during debootstrapping?

Tags: chroot, debootstrap

In a cleanly installed Ubuntu Raring machine I am trying to perform a `debootstrap` of another system. Here's the exact command:

```
http_proxy=http://192.168.122.1:8000/ debootstrap --arch=amd64 raring /mnt/virtfs-test/
```

It runs fine, but almost at the end it failed:

```
[...]
I: Extracting zlib1g...
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /mnt/virtfs-test mount -t proc proc /proc
W: See /mnt/virtfs-test/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details
```

The log file shows only this:

```
gpgv: Signature made Thu Apr 25 13:54:39 2013 CEST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"
gpgv: Signature made Thu Apr 25 13:54:39 2013 CEST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"
chroot: failed to run command 'mount': Permission denied
```

That made me curious on why this would fail. I noticed I couldn't even chroot into there:

```
chroot /mnt/virtfs-test 
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Permission denied
```

That led me to [this ServerFault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/162362/135437) and I made this interesting discovery:

```
# ls -al /mnt/virtfs-test/lib64/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 21 20:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Feb  7  2013 ..
----------  1 root  123    0 Aug 21 20:02 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

What? The file is not a link, it is empty and does not have any permission set? This makes no sense. So I linked the file as in the SF Q&A:

```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so /mnt/virtfs-test/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Now I can chroot:

```
# chroot /mnt/virtfs-test 
groups: cannot find name for group ID 0
I have no name!@mymachine:/#
```

However, I am still curious as to why debootstrap failed. I am using debootstrap version `1.0.46ubuntu1` which is the fully updated version in Ubuntu Raring. I am unable to find any bugreport regarding this.

Does anybody have a clue?

Notes:

- I performed all commands being fully root (`sudo -i`).
- The filesystem I try to debootstrap onto is type `9p` (VirtFS, inside a Ubuntu KVM virtual machine). I am not seeing any messages on the host machine after enabling this in the apparmor profile (`/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` on the host):

  ```
  /mnt/vms/virtfs-test/ rwl,
  /mnt/vms/virtfs-test/** rwl,
  ```

Comment: Seems likely to be a bug, however: It appears that the file (link) you were having trouble with should currently come from /mnt/virtfs-test/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb after being downloaded from the ubuntu archive. When that file is extracted to a temporary location does it contain the link in its lib64 or an empty file? (Does the file match what's above for libc6?) I assume you are running from an amd64 architecture raring.

Comment: lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is a link rather than an empty file on my system and comes from the above deb.